# Why would someone write string someString = "" + Convert.toChar(0) instead of someString = "0"

Tags: c#

Why would someone write

```
string someString = "" + Convert.ToChar(0);
```

instead of

```
string someString = "0";
```

I saw this in some code related to smart cards. Is there a particular reason for this, from a technical standpoint?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Asking about obfuscated code is a good thing to do.

Comment: From what it looks like it could be that the original programmer got confused a bit there with c/c++ as as the answers stated he effectively adds '\0' at the end of the string. That is only necesary in those languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Convert.ToChar(0)` is not the same as `'0'`. It is the same as `'\0'` (the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) or null terminator). Why would one use the `Convert` instead of `'\0'`? I see no reason why.

Using `"" +` before the character converts it to a `string` instead of an `char`. I prefer to use `.ToString()` since that makes clear what actually happens. But converting here is absolutely useless since you can simply construct a `string` at once. So conclusion, the code can be written the best as:

```
"\0"
```

Comment: I'm not certain they are equivalent: `"" + convertToChar(0)` has two null terminators appended, I *think*.

Comment: Why do you think the other string doesn't have that too. It is effectively the same code.

Comment: `"\0\0"` and `"\0"` differ from a memory perspective.

Comment: @Bathsheba Do .Net strings end in a null terminator that is visible to the user? I rather think you're confusing it with other languages.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure the C# specification is allowed to discard repeated "\0" a the end of a string. But this is a question in itself.

Comment: wouldn't "" + '\0` be in essence '\0' + '\0` ?  (in case c# does not discard repeated \0's

Comment: One slight difference: `"\0"` will be an interned string, as it is a comile time constant, while `"" + Convert.ToChar(0)` will not be interned.

Comment: In essence indeed. But if I set a string to "\0\0" then I can replace the zeroth character with confidence. I'm not an expert on this, as I'm sure you've figured out by now. In C and C++ I'm certainly correct.

Comment: I know you are :) @Bathsheba

Comment: @taffer according to wikipedia, string interning allows for faster processing i.e. string comparison. I'm probably stating what is obvious to you, but that could be a reason why this line was written in this way. Then again, in this specific case, the variable declared in this way was never used later on. Must be leftover code?

Answer (score 1):

`"0"` is a string literal consisting of the number zero and an embedded string terminator.

I *think* `"" + convertToChar(0)` has a string terminator due to `""` and another one due to `convertToChar(0)`. So it's still a zero length string.

Abbreviating the latter as `"\0"` is more conventional.